# What are the problems of these decision trees outputs?

Tags: classification, cart, multi-class

I have a report that using two structures of `decision trees` for a multi-class (4-classes) classification problem with 7 inputs. First output is for `CART` learning algorithm and second is for `C 5.0`. What do you think about these output? we have any obvious modeling problem or suspicious result in these output trees? Why in every step there isn't any error of classification? Both learning algorithms only used one variable (BE) as input?

[image: CART]

[image: C 5.0]

Comment: How many data points do you have? Have you tried anything along the lines of cross-validation? Is there any reason why you shouldn't be able to classify everything according to the "Be" variable? (What *is* the "Be" variable anyway and what are you trying to classify?)

Comment: As mentioned in report we have 1498 samples. They didn't use any cross-validation. Inputs are financial ratios here.

Comment: It looks to me like the "Be" variable was the variable used to generate the four classes themselves (i.e. the companies were split up by quartile). In that case it could be that whoever gathered the data left that column in there so that analysts (i.e. you) could have the freedom to do your own analysis (if you, for instance, wanted to split things up into a different group or turn it into a regression problem, etc.).